# Does a bijection between the atoms of two atomistic posets induce a bijection between the corresponding ground sets?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Recall that a poset $(X,\le)$ is said *atomistic* if every element may be expressed as (arbitrary) join of atoms. The most important case is the powerset lattice, where atoms are singletons. In such a case, notice that if there exists an order-preserving bijection between atoms, we can construct a bijection (an isomorphism) between the corresponding ground sets (in other terms, given an order-preseving map $F: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ which maps bijectively singletons to singletons, we can construct a bijection from $X$ to $Y$ using $F$). Does a similar property hold for any atomistic poset?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. You just said: if $F$ maps atoms to atoms bijectively, then $F$ restricted to atoms is a bijection. Well... sure, but this is a rather trivial statement. What kind of generalization to atomistic poset you are looking for?

Comment: @freakish I improved my question. I'm only saying that given an order-preserving functions sending bijectively singletons to singletons, I can construct a bijection from $X$ to $Y$. Now, my question is: does a similar property hold for any atomistic poset?

Comment: You don't need an order-preserving function. If a function maps singletons to singletons bijectively, then it induces a bijection. Regardless of whether it is order preserving or not. It all boils down to the fact that you can unpack a singleton $\{x\}$ into its value $x$. So what would be a similar property for atomistic posets? Given a function that maps atoms to atoms bijectively, does it induce bijection on atoms? As I said: its a trivial statement. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I find the question in the title clear enough, but then in the body of the post, you seem to ask something different, and I find very unclear what is it. For the question in the title the answer is clearly no. Take two posets with the same number of atoms, one of which with no elements above them, and the other with at least one element that is a join of at least two atoms. In the finite case, you can't  extend the obvious bijective map between the atoms to a bijection between the posets.

Comment: @freakish Why do you say that given a function that maps atoms to atoms bijectively, does it induce bijection on atoms? If $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{a,b,c\}$, you can take $f$ sending $0 \to b$, $1 \to a$ and $2 \to c$. Then you get a function $F: X \to Y$ defined through $f$. This is rather obvious. Note what are the domain and the range of $F$. Anyway the last comment seems to be quite interesting

Comment: @TheWanderer (1) I assume those posets are linear, i.e. $0<1<2$ and $a<b<c$, yes? If so, then your $f$ does not map atoms to atoms. The only atoms are $1$ in $X$ and $b$ in $Y$, but $f(1)=a$. (2) I don't get what your $F$ is in this example, the domain and range are the same of $f$, no? (3) Also the statement "$f:X\to Y$ maps $A$ to $B$ bijectively" and "$f:X\to Y$ induces bijection (by restriction) $f_{|A}:A\to B$" are almost the same.

Comment: But in the case of sets I'm working with the powerset lattice and not with a poset on $X$!

Comment: @TheWanderer so you are asking: if $X,Y$ are posets, $F:P(X)\to P(Y)$ is (some property here) then $F$ induces bijection between $atom(X)\to atom(Y)$? Is that your question? There is no relationship between powerset lattice and the original ordering on $X$ and $Y$. So I doubt you will find anything useful here.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ may not have any order structure. I have $X,Y$ sets and $F: P(X) \to P(Y)$ an order-preserving map whose restriction to atoms is bijective. Does $F$ induce a bijection between $X$ and $Y$. The answer is yes! Note that $X$ and $Y$ are the top elements of $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$. Put in a similar situation: you have two sets $X,Y$ being the top elements of an atomistic lattice and you know that in such an atomistic lattice there is an order-preserving map, sending bijectively atoms to atoms. May I construct a bijection from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: @TheWanderer $X$ is the set of all atoms of $P(X)$. Ok, formally it is the set of all singletons $\big\{ \{x\}\ |\ x\in X\big\}$, but it is obviously equinumerous with $X$ via $\{x\}\mapsto x$ unpacking. So the claim "$F$ induces a bijection between $X$ and $Y$" as a consequence of "$F$ maps atoms to atoms bijectively" is really trivial. The same logic applies to atomistic (or any) lattice, unless "top elements" does not mean "atoms". And again: whether $F$ is order preserving or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Not all atomistic lattices are powersets, so it may not even be obvious what "the ground set" of a given atomistic lattices is supposed to be (unless you define it as the set of atoms, which is a sensible choice but answers your question trivially).
For instance, consider a closure operator $cl$ on the set $X=\{0,1\}$ with  $cl(\emptyset)=\{0\}$ and $cl(\{1\})=X$. Then the lattice of closed subsets is just the same as $P(\{1\})$. In particular both have exactly one atom, but of course
there is no chance of obtaining a bijection betweeen $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1\}$.